# Translating from ZPL (Zebra Programming Language) to IPL (Intermec Programming Language)

Tags: zebra-printers, thermal-printer, zpl, intermec

I'm getting ready to embark on a week long adventure in translating a few print routines from ZPL to IPL.

Within the ZPL there exists a `Label Reverse Print` (^LRY) command. This command reverses the printing of all fields in the label format allowing a field to appear as white over black or black over white.

Does anyone know if a similar command exists within the IPL that performs such a task?

Printers:

- Zebra ZTC 105SL-200dpi
- Intermec 3400D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the equivalent command finally within IPL. The  `<SI>h` command selects the Printhead Loading Mode.